# What is wrong with auto?

Tags: c++, vector, auto

```
vector<int> function(vector<int> &arr)
{
    for(auto i = arr.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";

    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> arr{1,2,3,4};
    function(arr);
}
```

Why does the above program cycle? 
if I change `auto` with `int` everything is ok

Comment: ok but my index is not > 0

Comment: Move the decrement into the condition: `(auto i = arr.size(); (i--) > 0;)`. @M.M Better?

Comment: @Bob__ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c

Comment: What's the point of returning the unchanged `std::vector` that was passed into the function? Why not just return `void`?

Comment: IMHO, the best solution would be to use std::vector's const reverse iterator [for (auto i = arr.crend(); i != arr.crbegin(); i--)]. Also, as you don't change arr, its best to pass it as const ref. Otherwise, I agree with Jesper Juhl that you should return void, and with Blaze's answer.

Comment: The One way of using a range based for loop to iterate in reverse is to use `boost::adaptors::reverse`. [Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8GsZEg)

Comment: The `return arr` is very distracting from the issue, can we please remove it from your example and make the function return void?

Answer (score 9):

`arr.size()` is an **unsigned** data type, usually `size_t`. With `i` being unsigned, `i >= 0` is always `true`. Subtracting `1` from an unsigned variable that is `0` results in the biggest amount that the type can hold. As a result, it will cycle forever.

What then happens is uncertain, since your array index will turn into a gigantic value, and `arr[i]` will have undefined behavior for values `>= arr.size()`. If you have an `int` instead of `auto`, it works because the `i--` will cause it to eventually be `-1` and then `i >= 0` will be `false`, exiting the loop.

An explanation of this rollover behavior can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic):

> Unsigned integer arithmetic is always performed modulo 2<sup>n</sup>  where `n` is the number of bits in that particular integer. E.g. for unsigned int, adding one to `UINT_MAX` gives ​`0`​, and subtracting one from ​0​ gives `UINT_MAX`.

So, for `size_t`, subtracting `1` from `0` results in `SIZE_MAX`, which commonly has a value of `18446744073709551615`.

Comment: Although if it is `int` the loop will fail if the vector has more than `INT_MAX` objects

Comment: @M.M that's right. The best solution would probably be to change the loop condition so it doesn't have to rely on `i` becoming `-1`. Of course, for OP's example, `INT_MAX` is plenty.

Comment: Thanks i understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

What is you problem was already answered by Blaze and rafix07, but I wanted to add that in modern C++ its better to use iterators whenever possible. This has few advantages including code portability, better performance and more readable code.

Your code can look something like this:

```
std::vector<int> function(std::vector<int> &arr)
{
    for(auto it = arr.rbegin(); i != arr.rend(); ++i)
        std::cout << *it << " ";

    return arr;
}
```

or like this

```
std::vector<int> function(std::vector<int> &arr)
{
    std::for_each(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend(), [](int val) {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    });

    return arr;
}
```

or even like this

```
std::vector<int> function(std::vector<int> &arr)
{
    std::copy(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Very often you need the index.

Comment: @walnut You cannot traverse the reverse direction with range-for.

Comment: @vll Ah right, sorry. Still the wording "*in modern C++ its better to use iterators whenever possible*" seems strange to me when iterators have always been used in C++ and modern approaches go towards ranges instead.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, yes, it happens sometimes, though not that often in my practice, but anyway I really missed Python `enumerate()` at times. Fortunately we will have ranges soon...

Comment: @walnut, of course ranges are better, but they still not accessible to many projects due to requirements to use older C++ standard yet...

Comment: @vll you can, with a little help https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6HWBHF

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis you can get the index by subtracting addresses

Comment: If index is needed, [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) could also be useful.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a loop that goes the other way ( from max to 0 ) then you usually have this problem:

- Either the max is size_t so `i >= 0` is always true
- Or you change `i` to int so you have a comparison of a signed with an unsigned which would result in a compiler warning, or a comparison of an int to a larger size_t in x64.

Redesign the loop:

- Use a new type for `i` which would be long in x86 and long long in x64, now i >= 0 is good when your objects are not above 2^63 in x64 (most likely).
- when `i == 0`, break *inside* the loop.
- Change to the normal `i = 0` and `i < obj.size()` method.